# Math::BigFloat sometimes returns NaN from a division

Tags: perl, nan, division

I can't figure out why the result of a division is NaN, when previously, the result is the expected, while seemingly performing the same division.

When removing Math::BigFloat, Nan is not returned. But why is that happening?

The corresponding code (Perl):

```
use Math::BigFloat ':constant';

...

my $num1 = $sum_drmsd / $k_dists_num;
print "\nsum = $sum_drmsd DIV BY $k_dists_num = $num1\n";

if(looks_like_number($sum_drmsd)){

    print "numerator check ->> yes, is num.";
}

if (looks_like_number($k_dists_num)){
    print "\ndenominator check ->> yes, is num.";
}
print "\n";
```

The results:

```
sum = 11.2691792732961 DIV BY 10 = 1.12691792732961
numerator check ->> yes, is num.
denominator check ->> yes, is num.

sum = 13.4679575690216 DIV BY 10 = 1.34679575690216
numerator check ->> yes, is num.
denominator check ->> yes, is num.

sum = 10.9829799095931 DIV BY 10 = 1.09829799095931
numerator check ->> yes, is num.
denominator check ->> yes, is num.

sum = 11.2691792732961 DIV BY 10 = NaN
numerator check ->> yes, is num.
denominator check ->> yes, is num.

sum = 13.4679575690216 DIV BY 10 = NaN
numerator check ->> yes, is num.
denominator check ->> yes, is num.

sum = 10.9829799095931 DIV BY 10 = NaN
numerator check ->> yes, is num.
denominator check ->> yes, is num.
```

EDIT:

Data::Dumper output in each case:

```
$sum_drmsd = '10.9829799095931';
$k_dists_num = '10';
1.9997

$sum_drmsd = '10.9829799095931';
$k_dists_num = bless( {
                        'sign' => '+',
                        'value' => [
                                     10
                                   ]
                      }, 'Math::BigInt' );
1.9997
```

Comment: Could you add more code so we can try reproduce the behavior?

Comment: `looks_like_number` isn't very useful here. It simply stringifies the value and confirms that the resultant string "looks like a number" which, having been derived from one, it is pretty much bound to do. As has been said, we can't help you much unless you show the code that generated `$sum_drmsd` and `$k_dists_num`.

Comment: Thank you. $k_dists_num is a value immediately received by the function as an argument and $sum_drmsd is intialized to 0 and then used in a loop to add values that are received from a matrix. It would me many lines to post all the "participating" code. So, I assume there is no somewhat easy way to detect what may be going wrong in that final level of forming $num1.

Comment: show the output of `use Data::Dumper; print Data::Dumper->new([$sum_drmsd,$k_dists_num], ["sum_drmsd","k_dists_num"])->Dump, $Math::BigFloat::VERSION, "\n"`; that should help us duplicate the problem

Comment: Thank you. I added the output in each case.

Comment: Are you setting `precision` or `accuracy` (or some such) anywhere?  That `10` could be getting rounded to `0`.   How does this behave if you use the module's `bdiv` instead of `/`?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this.  Which version of perl?  Which version of Math::BigFloat?

Comment: I think this needs an [mcve] - we really need something reproducible.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry I've taken so long to get around to looking at this.

The problem is that `use Math::BigFloat` doesn't automatically make all floating point arithmetic use the module; it just provides the code for creating `Math::BigFloat` objects if you write your program that way, like any other object-oriented module

The module *overloads* the arithmetic operators, so that division `$x / $y` is executed as a call to `$x->bdiv($y)`. From that it's much clearer that `$x` must be an object (as simple numbers don't have a `bdiv` method) but in fact `$y` may be an object, a number, or a numeric string. The module will convert the second parameter to an object if a simple number is passed

In your code `$sum_drmsd` is not a `Math::BigFloat` object, it is just a floating point value. That is why I asked you where the values came from, but your answer doesn't really help much as I need to know their *origins*

> `$k_dists_num` is a value immediately received by the function as an argument and `$sum_drmsd` is intialized to 0 and then used in a loop to add values that are received from a matrix

From the dumps you show, `$k_dists_num` is a `Math::BigInt` object, which is fine. But `$sum_drmsd` needs to be initialised to `Math::BigFloat->bzero` instead of just `0`, otherwise you're just accumulating ordinary numbers

This code demonstrates the problem

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Math::BigFloat;

my $k_dists_num = Math::BigInt->new('10');
my $sum_drmsd   = 0;

$sum_drmsd += 10.9829799095931;

my $quot = $sum_drmsd / $k_dists_num;

print "sum = $sum_drmsd / $k_dists_num = $quot\n";
```

#### output

```perl
sum = 10.9829799095931 / 10 = NaN
```

But if I change just the line

```
my $sum_drmsd = 0
```

to

```perl
my $sum_drmsd = Math::BigFloat->bzero
```

then I get this correct output instead

#### output

```
sum = 10.9829799095931 / 10 = 1.09829799095931
```

Note that I also recommend removing the `:constant` option, as otherwise it's easy to become confused over which variables are `Math::BigFloat` objects and which are simple numbers (as you have done!)